# Xpath array for child elements

Tags: arrays, xpath, wildcard, wget

I have a an xpath code which returns multiple variable child elements
i want to be able to read each child element.

Is it possible to create an array or is there some other way to pass a wildcard into xpath to pull all child elements?

Example:

```
<changeSet>
<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>
</changeSet>
```

The number of items could vary.
I would like to be able to read all items that might show up when i run the query.

Comment: what are you running the xpath in? javascript? xslt? something else?

Comment: I am running xpath as part of a wget command.

Comment: @user2187297: To add a bit more context to your question, please add the (exemplary) wget comment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with pure XPath 1.0 the expression `/changeSet/item` returns a set of all `item` element nodes that are children of the `changeSet` root element. Or `/changeSet/*` returns all child elements of the `changeSet` root elements. Of course depending on the XPath API you use you might get acollection or a list or array of nodes or in the worst case only the string value of the first selected node. In that case you need to look at the XPath API you use, it should offer an option to return a collection of nodes.